# Converting pixels to points in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I need to put a 1 point empty box around an image in Photoshop for a file that is 600 dpi.

No matter what I try, I can get the line to look right.

How many pixels should I use?

Comment: In all Adobe applications 1 point = 1 pixel

Answer (score 3):

One inch equals 72 points. The resolution of your image is 600 pixels per inch. So one point in your particular image is:

`(600 pixels/inch) / (72 points/inch) = 8.33 pixels ≈ 8 pixels`

But you don't have to do the math yourself. Most input fields in Photoshop accepts numbers with units. So if you for example make a selection, right click and select *Stroke*, you can enter *1 pt* in the *Width* field and Photoshop will automatically change the value to *8 px*.

Since you want to make a stroke with a certain physical width I assume this is for print. Be advised that it might not be a good idea to add such a stroke directly in the image. The image might be placed in a layout program and resized slightly which will alter the width of the stroke. Additionally a stroke in an image will probably get screen dots along the edge on print and seem a little blurred. It's better to add strokes like that in a vector layout program where the stroke will be sharp vector and isn't dependent on the scale of the image.